# How to use one relational(postGreSql) and one non-relational(MongoDb) database in single node.js application

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, postgresql

I have to work on one Node Js project where I have to use two database in single application, One database is MongoDb and the other one is postgreSql. Till now I have only used only one dababase in one project. I just want to know that "Is it possible to use two different database as mentioned above in one Node Js project". If yes can you please provide me essential configs and plugin required to setup the project ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah... NoSQL & another RDBMS together...because

NoSQL:  fast and simple, but has little to none structure to enforce constraints on data.

RDBMS: satisfies all ACID  properties, keeping your data safe and clean. But performance goes down rapidly as traffic and data set size grow.

for doing so ..

you can use an  ODM (Object Document Mapper) like [mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/) to deal with mongoDB

& an ORM (Object Relational Mapper) like [sequalize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/) to deal with mysql , postgre

As provided in the docs.. you got to install both

**npm i -s mongoose sequelize**

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I got my answer

Comment: Yeah... Sure I will definitely try it.
Thank you